# How to find find the equation of conjugate hyperbola given a general hyperbola

Tags: analytic-geometry, coordinate-systems

For any general hyperbola

S:ax$^2$+2hxy+by$^2$+2gx+2fy+c=0

Given discriminant $\Delta\neq$ 0

How would I obtain the equation of its conjugate?

When I tried this I began to question what exactly the hyperbola and its conjugate had in common or differed in and the only possible approach I got was somehow finding the transverse and conjugate axes and interchanging them to give the conjugate but it was way too tedious.

However the final expression is

S':ax$^2$+2hxy+by$^2$+2gx+2fy+c-$\frac{2\Delta}{ab-h^2} $=0

This seems fairly similar to the equation of the assymptotes

L:ax$^2$+2hxy+by$^2$+2gx+2fy+c-$\frac{\Delta}{ab-h^2} $=0

What's the best way I can proceed with?

Comment: If you want to proceed that way, note the relations between hyperbola $Q_h=x^2/a^2-y^2/b^2-1=0$, conjugate hyperbola $Q_c=x^2/a^2-y^2/b^2+1=0$ and the asymptotes $Q_a=x^2/a^2-y^2/b^2=0$ is $Q_h+Q_c-2Q_a=0$ and invariance under rotation and translation gives the result.

Comment: @user10354138 Wow that's a pretty good observation! Invariance under translation makes sense but how can say it is invarient under rotation?